# Django models in file sharing system

Tags: django, django-models, file-sharing

models.py :

`class Document(models.Model):
     docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank= False)`

I have created a model for file upload as shown above. docfile is the field that represents file to be uploaded and user field stores the name of the user that is uploading the file.I want the additional fields so that file uploaded is visible to the ones with whom it has been shared. Tell me the fields for achieving the sharing task.

Comment: is your documents folder under `/var/www` by any chance?

Comment: @Sayse No, it is created by me in my django project folder.

Answer (score 1):

You would another field which has a foreign key to Django User Model.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank= False)
```

then whenever you want to fetch documents based on the logged in user, you would use this

```
docs = Document.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: the user field tells only the files uploaded by the user but how to create fields for sharing the files. I want to share the file with at max 100 users, how the fields are to be defined.

Comment: you should check out [Django docs on Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/) . Kindly let me know if you find the link useful

Comment: `users = model.ManyToMany(User)` should solve the problem. This means a user can have multiple docs, likewise docs could belong to multiple users

Comment: I think there should be many to many relationship between files and users. But how to establish it and call it in views?

Answer (score 0):

**In models.py**

`users = model.ManyToMany(User)`
this should work, although am not so sure. But feel free to let me know if you by chance run into any problem

**In views.py**

`docs = Document.users.filter(username=request.user.username)`